# CSRF Failed when POST data using Alamofire

Tags: django-rest-framework, alamofire

I using django-reat-framework as backend and using SessionAuthentication and TokenAuthentication.
This work well when I use httpie send request

`http POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ email="abc@abc.com" user_name="abc" passwod="1234"`

but when I use Alamofire

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/", parameters: ["email": emailField.text!, "user_name": usernameField.text!, "password": passwordField.text!], encoding: .URL )
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("JSON: \(JSON)")
                }
        }
```

return this

```
Optional(<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7fe24e15d640> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ })
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7fe24bf3a080> { URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ } { status code: 403, headers {
    Allow = "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Fri, 11 Mar 2016 13:09:59 GMT";
    Server = "WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.4.3";
    Vary = "Accept, Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
} })
Optional(<7b226465 7461696c 223a2243 53524620 4661696c 65643a20 43535246 20746f6b 656e206d 69737369 6e67206f 7220696e 636f7272 6563742e 227d>)
SUCCESS
JSON: {
    detail = "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.";
}
```

But 127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/ don't need any permission, and I didn't send csrf token when I using httpie.So, What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This header worked for me:

```
let headers = [
   "Cookie": ""
]


Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: ["username": username!, "password": password!],encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON {
    response in
    switch response.result {
           case .success:
                print(response)                    
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
    }

}
```

From here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/646

Answer (score 1):

POST/DELETE requests to API created using Django need a valid csrftoken to be passed along with the request.

You need to generate the token before you make any POST calls. To generate the token please refer to 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/

Also after getting the csrftoken value from the cookie, pass the token in the header of the request

```
        let headers = [ "Accept":"application/json" ,  "Content-Type": "application/json" , "X-CSRFToken" : csrftoken]


        Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/", headers: headers, parameters: params, encoding:  .JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in

                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let responseContent):
```

Comment: Can you please provide your solution to generate the token?

Answer (score -1):

Take off **SessionAuthentication** from **authentication_classes** in the corresponding API view. It will "disable" cookies for this view, which means **CSRF-token won't be required anymore**.